# how to specify aaSorting based on th-class

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the [dataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin, and I want to control the initial sorting by the **class name** of the column and not by the **index**.

I found this solution: http://live.datatables.net/awunaw/edit#javascript,html but it wouldn't work for me, because I have multiple `table` on the same page.

**Edit:**

```
<table class="dataTables" >
   <thead>
      <th>Num</th>
      <th class="defaultSort">Date</th>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>   <td>1/1/13</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


 <table class="dataTables" >
    <thead>
       <th class="defaultSort">Num</th>
       <th>Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>11</td>   <td>1/1/13</td>
       </tr>
    <tbody>
 </table>

 jQuery('table.dataTable').dataTable(dataTablesDefaultOption);
```

Comment: Why does it not work with multiples tables on the same page? It should not be any problem.

Comment: show your HTML / script!!

Comment: I can't use `$('table.dataTables th.defaultSort').index('table.dataTables th');` because I've two `table.dataTables`

Comment: Forgot - see now after you have posted the code that you miss `<thead>` section - programmatically sorting will not work without it! see http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9432/cannot-read-property-assorting-of-undefined-in-datatables-1.9/p1

Comment: Actually I use `<thead>` in my code, I just forgot it when I wrote the above code

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution:

```
jQuery("th.dateSort").click();
```